# Please show more OpenID options automatically

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, login

When I log in to a Stack Exchange site, I'm presented with the logo of a few OpenID providers. Since I don't use any of the big 5, I need to click on “More OpenID options…” to be able to type my OpenID.

[image: More OpenID options]

Please always show the full set of options. The need for an extra click is confusing (uh? you mean I can't log in if I don't have an account at one of these?), and there aren't so many extra options that hiding them could be useful.

N.B. Although this post has been marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), my request has not been implemented. The gratuitous click is still necessary in a majority of cases — if it's the first time you use a particular browser profile (i.e. every time you log in from a new machine), unless your OpenID is one of the privileged 5, you need to click on “More OpenID options”.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that these *used* to be visible. Hiding them must be a new feature since I had to log in.

Comment: @Cody: Yes, I don't remember seeing that before. I couldn't find any mention on Meta.

Answer (score 4):

... sort of.

Now, if you expand the more options thing we attach a cookie that will auto-expand it in the future.

This was changed in the first place because a very common complaint about our sites is that login is rather intimidating.  Removing 8 buttons and a (rather large) text box goes a long way to alleviating that.

Comment: That's a fantastic compromise. Simple, elegant, and targeted.

Comment: What difference does this change make in practice? Since SE logins last forever, if I'm logging in, it's probably because I've never logged in on this particular site with this particular browser instance, so I don't have a cookie. I think my complaint is exactly opposite to that prior complaint: login is now *even more* intimidating (it looks like I absolutely need to have an account at one of the five).

Comment: [This has been re-requested.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118933/awkward-ux-on-the-login-page-for-self-hosted-openid-users)

Comment: With the other login options as tiny icons, I don't see why it's intimidating. The cookie is of no use for me because my cookies get cleared everytime I close the browser. For me and a lot of others, it's a lot simpler to not have to click on the "show more login options" link. Please remove that link. Even Joel says something about these tiny annoyances: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000057.html

Comment: @Nav the article you linked could do with a *YouTube* style *Thumbs up if you are still reading this in 2012!!*

Comment: There's an SO style thumbs up shaped as an arrow pointing upoward beside every comment on this page, if that's what you're looking for :)