# Awkward UX on the login page for self-hosted OpenID users

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, user-interface, openid, login

The login page for all SE sites was revised a while ago and the self-hosted OpenID form field was hidden behind an ajaxy mouseclick.

I use my own endpoint on a personal domain to login (christopher.woods.name) and I'm sure others do the same -- it wouldn't compromise the page design if the OpenID form field was displayed all the time, with the buttons for third party OpenID servers now on the site it disambiguates the OpenID-specific form fields. Can the text field for custom OpenID URLs be reincluded on the login page without having to reveal it via an extra mouseclick?

It's a small request, but one which would make me far less frustrated every time I log in. :-)

Comment: awwww! kittehs!

Comment: Duplicate: [Please show more OpenID options automatically](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91715) But I'm not voting to close because my request was marked [meta-tag:status-completed] in spite of not having been implemented in any useful way.

Comment: I use a custom OpenID myself, and even I think it's better as it is, for the very reasons in Piskvor's answer.

Answer (score 3):

I use a custom OpenID endpoint, too; but I believe the UX is based on diminishing returns: Most users logging in are going to use the big 5; making all the possible options visible by default would IMNSHO clutter the login page and make it harder to understand.

Apart from that, how often do you login that one extra mouseclick is a significant obstacle? On my computers, I'm logging in once a day, *at the very most*...

Comment: The fact that there are still people using custom OpenID endpoints means that we should be able to login as easily as everyone else. I'd wager there's not going to be a *decrease* in people using "other" OpenID servers to log in so I find it frustrating that I have to click and click again.

Comment: Also my browsers don't autofill the text field because it's hidden by default, that's also a bit frustrating.

Comment: Logging in today, I can see the custom endpoint textbox is now being shown by default -- hurrah! It's a small but worthwhile improvement.

Comment: @ChristopherWoods note: it isn't shown by default, but remembers if you expanded the box now, enjoy!