# Why doesn't quant.stackexchange.com auto login?

Tags: support, user-interface, login

I start off by logging into Stack Overflow via my OpenID login. Then I go to Stack Exchange and navigate to several other Stack Exchange sites. I get auto logged into them. I go to `quant.stackexchange.com` and it does not login me in. None of the login choices are OpenID. What should I do? Does quant.stackexchange.com require a completely separate login?

Comment: *"None of the login choices are OpenID"* — did you [click "Show more login options"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SVjIH.png)?

Comment: The user interface is gratuitously annoying and confusing: you need to click “show more login options” every time. See [Please show more OpenID options automatically](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91715) and [Awkward UX on the login page for self-hosted OpenID users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118933)

Comment: @Gilles seeing a massive amount of buttons was more annoying an confusing for the large majority of users who don't even know what OpenID is, let alone know their OpenID URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I go to https://quant.stackexchange.com/users/login,and I am not logged-in, I see a page containing the following.

[image: screenshot]

When I click on the "Show more login options" link, the page changes to show more options.

[image: screenshot]

All those options are for OpenID logins, and the options you see there are not different from what you see in other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Nice that this apparently solved the issue for the OP, but I'm not sure how this relates to auto login? (The OP does have their accounts associated, [so it seems](http://stackexchange.com/users/17766/4thspace?tab=accounts).)

Comment: (As an aside, [balpha wrote a year ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91916/no-auto-login-for-some-ses/91918#91918) that auto login will only try once for each site on regular pages, but should always try on the login page.)